# how to specify obj and bin directories in GNUmake

Tags: gnu-make

I have a following directory structure,

I also have this make file that works fine, but it needs all files in the same directory and also it creates *.o and bin files in the same directory. Can someone please show me how to improve this code so that i can move *.h files into /h, *.c files into /src. Also *.o files would be created in /obj and the binary file will be created in /bin?

I was thinking of something like this. This part only creates *.o files, no binary files. However, this is giving me an error right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: `h/`**

Add a variable, make a small change to the `%.o` rule, and add a `vpath` directive, so that the `%.o` rule will know where to look:

```
INC_DIR = h
%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -I$(INC_DIR) -c $<

vpath %.h $(INC_DIR)
```

**Step 2: `src/`**

Add another variable, change the assignment of `objs`, add another `vpath`:

```
SRC_DIR := src
objs:=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c))

vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)
```

**Step 3: `obj/`**

Add a variable, change `objs` and the `%.o` rule again, and the `clean` rule:

```
OBJ_DIR = obj
objs:=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -Ih -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.d $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(prog)
```

**Step 4: `bin/`**

Add another variable, and change the assignment of `prog`:

```
BIN_DIR := bin
prog:=$(BIN_DIR)/$(notdir $(PWD))
```

**EDIT:**

What you are now asking for is a bad design. But here it is:

obj/makefile:

```
SRC_DIR := ../src
objs:=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c))

cc:=gcc

.PHONY: ALL_OBJS
ALL_OBJS: $(objs)

INC_DIR := ../h
%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -I$(INC_DIR) -c $<

vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)

.PHONY: clean test

clean:
    rm -f *.[od]

-include *.d
```

bin/makefile:

```
P:= $(PWD)
P:= $(dir $(P))
prog:= $(notdir $(P:/=))

OBJ_DIR := ../obj
objs:=$(notdir $(wildcard $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o))

cc:=gcc
ccflags:=-lcurses -lgdbm -lgdbm_compat

$(prog): $(objs)
    $(cc) $(ccflags) -o $@ $^

vpath %.o $(OBJ_DIR)

.PHONY: clean test

clean:
    rm -f *.d $(prog)

test: $(prog)
    $(test)

-include *.d
```

Comment: Is there a way to write a target to only create object files? Also another target to only link object files and create the binary file? I wanted to break this into 2 different steps, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @usustarr, I don't understand. The `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:` rule creates object files. Do you mean a rule that will create *all* of the object files? The `$(prog):` rule links the object files into the executable binary file (and requires that all of the objects files be built first).

Comment: The rule $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: rule creates object files & links all the object files to make the binary, correct? Imgine a situvation where I only want to create object files. Then based on some other condition, I deside if I want to create the binary file or not. 

In other words, lets say I have a 1 make file that sits in /obj it only creates *.o files. The other make file sits in /bin. It only knows how to use *.o files in the /obj to create the bin file. How do I do something like this?